# How to merge two dataframes on a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

What I am looking to create is a dataframe which looks like:

```
    amount  months      category    
0   6460    2018-01-31  budgeted    
1   7905    2018-01-31  actual  
2   11509   2018-02-28  budgeted    
3   21502   2018-02-28  actual 
...
...
```

The sample code I have and base datafrom I am working with is:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import altair as alt

from random import randint

# 
# This is the general form of my 'real' dataframe. It is not subject to change.
#
months                  = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
monthyAmounts           = [ "actual", "budgeted", "difference" ]

summary = []

summary.append( [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ] )
summary.append( [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ]  )
summary.append( [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ]  )

index   = pd.Index( [ 'Income', 'Expenses', 'Difference' ], name = 'type' )
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [months, monthyAmounts], names=['month', 'category'] )

summaryDF = pd.DataFrame( summary, index = index, columns = columns )

#
# From this point, I am trying to transform the summaryDF into something 
# I can use in a different context...
#

budgetMonths = pd.date_range( "January, 2018", periods = 12, freq = 'BM' )

idx = pd.IndexSlice
budgeted = summaryDF.loc[ 'Difference', idx[:, 'budgeted' ] ].cumsum()
actual   = summaryDF.loc[ 'Difference', idx[:, 'actual' ] ].cumsum()

budgeted.index = budgetMonths
actual.index = budgetMonths

budgetedDF = pd.DataFrame( { 'amount': budgeted, 'months': budgetMonths, 'category': 'budgeted' })
actualDF   = pd.DataFrame( { 'amount': actual, 'months': budgetMonths, 'category': 'actual' })

print( budgetedDF )
print( actualDF )

df3 = pd.merge( budgetedDF, actualDF, on = 'months' )
df3
```

df3 looks like:

```
    amount_x    months      category_x  amount_y    category_y
0   6460        2018-01-31  budgeted    7905        actual
1   11509       2018-02-28  budgeted    21502       actual
...
...
```

I think I am close to getting what I want...just need the final merge step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Merge" these DataFrames using `pd.concat`.

```
df3 = (pd.concat([budgetedDF, actualDF])
         .sort_index()
         .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```
df3

    amount  category     months
0     2183  budgeted 2018-01-31
1     3612    actual 2018-01-31
2     8902  budgeted 2018-02-28
3     3357    actual 2018-02-28
4     9956  budgeted 2018-03-30
5     2828    actual 2018-03-30
6    14475  budgeted 2018-04-30
7     2990    actual 2018-04-30
8    25385  budgeted 2018-05-31
9     4446    actual 2018-05-31
10   19119    actual 2018-06-29
11   29119  budgeted 2018-06-29
12   27296    actual 2018-07-31
13   40869  budgeted 2018-07-31
14   38443    actual 2018-08-31
15   43400  budgeted 2018-08-31
16   47978    actual 2018-09-28
17   52686  budgeted 2018-09-28
18   49612    actual 2018-10-31
19   63384  budgeted 2018-10-31
20   49272    actual 2018-11-30
21   74107  budgeted 2018-11-30
22   83653  budgeted 2018-12-31
23   56907    actual 2018-12-31
```

However, you might prefer this representation instead:

```
df3 = (pd.concat([budgetedDF, actualDF])
         .drop('months', 1)
         .set_index('category', append=True)
         .unstack()
)

df3
           amount         
category   actual budgeted
2018-01-31   3612     2183
2018-02-28   3357     8902
2018-03-30   2828     9956
2018-04-30   2990    14475
2018-05-31   4446    25385
2018-06-29  19119    29119
2018-07-31  27296    40869
2018-08-31  38443    43400
2018-09-28  47978    52686
2018-10-31  49612    63384
2018-11-30  49272    74107
2018-12-31  56907    83653
```

Comment: The concat line after 'you might prefer this representation instead' is not the representation I ultimately need as noted at the top of my post. The reason is that I need a representation that is friendly with how altair wants to generate graphs from dataframes.

Comment: @ericg Sure, it's your call. Just letting you know these are your options. I don't know about altair so I couldn't have known either way.

Comment: Thank you. It is appreciated. I am still not sure how your concat really differs from the other answer.

Comment: @ericg They are effectively the same, but I covered more bases than fuglede did in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is

```
pd.concat([budgetedDF, actualDF]).sort_values('months').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: How is this merging on common month values?

Comment: @coldspeed: They want to keep separate values for each value of `months`, as I read the desired behavior at the top of the post.

Comment: No, they're doing a merge on months at the bottom of their script, via `pd.merge( budgetedDF, actualDF, on = 'months' )`. The result has one row from each dataFrame after the merge.

Comment: And that behavior is exactly what they're trying to avoid as I read it.

Comment: No, see. They want to merge on common months and then have the merged result exist as separate rows. They've even used an explicit indicator column.

Comment: They already have that though; if you include a `reset_index(drop=True)` in your final line, our results are exactly identical.

Comment: I'm not sure we're getting through to each other, and I'm not sure who's right here. So I've edited my post in the hope that OP figures out who's answered their question correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea; thanks. In either case, the latter representation that you provide seem like it ought to be preferable in most situations.

Comment: based on what I am seeing, both of your answers are producing the same final result. Coldspeed, as my dataframes have the same length, I skipped your steps 1 & 2.

Comment: You can see something closer to my 'real' case here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/altair-viz/bF_weOdVYy4 (the second post actually uses coldspeeds, answer, but fuglede seems to work just as well. So, I am not sure who is right or what the real difference is between the answers.

Comment: And, yes, I believe fuglede is right when he is saying 'that behavior is exactly what they're trying to avoid'. I believe I clearly do not want to merge on months. I need the concat as you both noted.